# Re-using Object(s) from another Django App's Model

Tags: django, django-models

I'm newer to python, and newer to writing "web apps" but not new to the industry.

I'm working on building a site in Mezzanine which is a Django project.  I want to build a content type for "Portfolios" which would pull a single image for each gallery content type.

My question is (keep in mind, per the documentation I can't subclass the GalleryImage type):

- Should I copy the objects & specific attributes to my model?
- Is there better approach to this?

Here's the data model:
http://mezzanine.jupo.org/docs/_images/graph.png

Here's the documentation on custom content types:
http://mezzanine.jupo.org/docs/content-architecture.html#the-page-model

## Edit

I'd like to further clarify what I'm trying to do.

What I want this "content-type" to do is create a single thumbnail from each "gallery" that is a child of this  "content-type". Display each thumbnail as a link to each of the galleries.

Example:

Portfolio Page - Display a single photo from "Landscape photography" & "City life photography"
|
|----Landscape photography (w / 7 photos)
|----City life photography (w / 7 photos)
|----etc

Maybe I'm asking a dumb question.

Should I be copying the file path from the "Gallery" model to my "Portfolio" model?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand the question, but take a look at the docs on model subclassing: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#model-inheritance

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to review my question @WilHall I made an edit to try and further clarify.